# Not able to call a method through reflection

Tags: java, reflection, exception

The following is my method and i try to call the method using Reflection in java:

```
@PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated() and hasPermission(#request, 'CREATE_REQUISITION')")
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/trade/createrequisition")
    public @ResponseBody
    void createRequisition(@RequestBody CreateRequisitionRO[] request,
            @RequestHeader("validateOnly") boolean validateOnly) {
        logger.debug("Starting createRequisition()...");
        for (int i = 0; i < request.length; i++) {
            CreateRequisitionRO requisitionRequest = request[i];

            // FIXME this has to be removed/moved
            requisitionRequest.setFundManager(requisitionRequest.getUserId());
            // FIXME might have to search using param level as well
            SystemDefault sysDefault = dbFuncs.references.systemDefault
                    .findByCompanyAndDivisionAndPortfolio(
                            userContext.getCompany(),
                            userContext.getDivision(),
                            requisitionRequest.getPortfolio());
            requisitionRequest.setCustodianN(sysDefault.getCustodianN());

            gateKeeper.route(requisitionRequest);
        }
    }
```

the way i create Reflection :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Class[] paramString = new Class[1]; 
        paramString[0] = String.class;

        //Object parameter
        Class[] parames = new Class[1]; 
        parames[0] = CreateRequisitionRO.class;

        Class booleanVal ;  
        booleanVal = Boolean.class;


        Class cls;
        CreateRequisitionRO[] request = new CreateRequisitionRO[10];
        try {
            //load the HexgenWebAPI at runtime
            cls = Class.forName("com.hexgen.api.facade.HexgenWebAPI");
            Object obj = cls.newInstance();

            Method method = cls.getDeclaredMethod("createRequisition", parames,booleanVal);
            method.invoke(obj, request,true);


        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

i get the following exception :

```
The method getDeclaredMethod(String, Class...) in the type Class is not applicable for the arguments (String, Class[], Class)
```

at the following line

Method method = cls.getDeclaredMethod("createRequisition", parames,booleanVal);

I understand the exception but my method argument is array of objects. if i remove array than i get `NoSuchMethod Exception`

how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass a class of the `CreateRequisitionRO` array, not an array of classes: replace this

```
Class[] parames = new Class[1]; 
parames[0] = CreateRequisitionRO.class;
```

with this:

```
Class parames = CreateRequisitionRO[].class;
```

In addition, since the second parameter is `boolean`, not `Boolean`, you need to replace

```
booleanVal = Boolean.class; // The class of the wrapper Boolean
```

with

```
booleanVal = Boolean.TYPE;  // The class of the primitive boolean
```

Comment: Great Observation, It resolved the compile time problem. but i now get this `java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`. Could you guide me? Meanwhile i will accept this as answer with upvote. :)

Comment: @Anto `InvocationTargetException` means that the implementation of the method threw an error. Catch it in your code, call `getCause()` on it, and see what's the real cause of your exception was. At this point, the problem will be in the segment at the top of your post, or in the default constructor that you call from `newInstance()`.